# S3 trigger didn't invoke Lambda when a file is uploaded on S3 automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I created a Lambda function that gets data from S3 and puts it into DynamoDB. I enabled S3 event notification on my bucket, so whenever a file is uploaded on S3 it automatically fetches data and puts it into a DynamoDB table. This worked absolutely fine when I uploaded a file on s3.

I have scheduled Amazon Connect reports to the S3 bucket that automatically sends a CSV report to S3 after 30 minutes intervals.

**Problem**

When a 30 minute interval completes Amazon Connect sends a report to S3 and my S3 bucket sends event to Lambda function. But this time, it throws an error that I have checked through CloudWatch.

**Error**

```
[ERROR] NoSuchKey: An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified key does not exist.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 17, in lambda_handler
    file_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=source_bucket_name,Key=file_name)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 386, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 705, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
```

**Lambda Code**

```
import json 
import boto3 

s3_client = boto3.client("s3") 
dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
student_table = dynamodb.Table('AgentAvailibilityReport')
 
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("starting AgentAvailibilityReport")
    
    source_bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    file_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    #print(source_bucket_name)
    #print(file_name)

    
    file_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=source_bucket_name,Key=file_name)
    print("file_object :",file_object)
    
    file_content = file_object['Body'].read().decode("utf-8")
    print("file_content :",file_content)
    
    temp = file_content.split("\n")
    lastIndex = len(temp)-1
    students = temp[1:lastIndex]   
    print("lenght", len(students))
    print("students :",students)
    for student in students:
        data = student.split(",")
        print("printing student objects")
        print(data)
        try:
            student_table.put_item(
                Item = {
                            "Agent" : data[0],
                            "StartInterval" : data[1],
                            "EndInterval" : data[2],
                            "Agent idle time" : data[3],
                            "Contacts missed" : data[4],
                            "Agent on contact time" : data[5],
                            "Nonproductive time" : data[6],
                            "After contact work time" : data[7]
                } )
               
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Same code is perfectly working for manual execution but it throws error on automation. Kindly help me here.

Comment: The title does not seem to say something entirely different compared to the body. Log / `print` the event to see what it contains, or uncomment the two prints of the bucket and file_name. Then check if the object is actually in the bucket. Maybe someone sent a nonesense message to your lambda or the file was removed, if it was removed, maybe temporarily enable versioning on the bucket to see creates and deletes in the ui...

Comment: After uncommenting, I checked the Cloudwatch, it is showing the correct bucket name but showing incorrect file_name or key.

Comment: The actual file is uploaded with the name of "AgentAvailibilityReport-2022-03-02T13:00:00Z.csv", but it automatically changed the file_name at the end "AgentAvailibilityReport-2022-03-02T13%3A00%3A00Z.csv"

Comment: `:` in file names are a bad idea and need special handling: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-keys.html

Comment: Try: `file_name = unquote_plus(event['Records']['s3']['object']['key'])` and use `from urllib.parse import unquote_plus`. Also, note that you are only processing the first record in event['Records']. It's a list. There could potentially be multiple records. I haven't actually seen multiple with S3 as an event source but it's simple to convert this code into a loop.

Answer (score 0):

My problem got solved when I got to know my file contains a colon(:) in its name, which is not acceptable by S3. Because it changes the file name automatically. I handle that issue in my Lambda function with minor changes in code. I have used replace method to fix the issue.

```
import json 
import os
import boto3 

s3_client = boto3.client("s3") 
dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
student_table = dynamodb.Table('AgentAvailibilityReport')
 
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("starting AgentAvailibilityReport")
    
    source_bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    #print(source_bucket_name)
    print(key)
    old = '%3A'
    new = ':'
    file_name = key.replace(old,new)
    print(file_name)
    file_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=source_bucket_name,Key=file_name)
    print("file_object :",file_object)
    
    file_content = file_object['Body'].read().decode("utf-8")
    print("file_content :",file_content)
    
    temp = file_content.split("\n")
    lastIndex = len(temp)-1
    students = temp[1:lastIndex]   
    print("lenght", len(students))
    print("students :",students)
    id=0
    for student in students:
        data = student.split(",")
        print("printing student objects")
        print(data)
        try:
            student_table.put_item(
                Item = {
                            "id" : id,
                            "Agent" : data[0],
                            "StartInterval" : data[1],
                            "EndInterval" : data[2],
                            "Agent idle time" : data[3],
                            "Contacts missed" : data[4],
                            "Agent on contact time" : data[5],
                            "Nonproductive time" : data[6],
                            "After contact work time" : data[7]
                } )
            id = id+1   
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```